# Why .NET framework V4.8 installed in Windows Server 2012R does not exist in registry?

Tags: .net, windows, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed .NET framework V4.8 in Windows Server 2012R by running installer ndp48-devpack-enu-exe in command line using following command:
`ndp48-devpack-enu.exe /q /norestart`
I implemented a solution using .NET framework but I got an target-of-invokation error
I checked files were installed in disk but I realized version in registry was not updated.
What I did wrong? Would you please advise

I did install same file in a development environment by double-clicking (different) and worked, but I don't dare in former one as it is a production environment and don't want to mess with the server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems

Comment: I hope you are aware that 2012R2 is now completely out of support...